# React UseEffect hook Issue Rendering an Interval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In the following React Component below, I am trying to add increment count by each second passed so it looks like a stopwatch, but the count is shown as 2, then blinks to 3, and back to 2. Does anyone know how to deal with this bug, and get the count to show up as intended?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const IntervalHook = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const tick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [ count ]);

  return <h1> {count} </h1>;
};

export default IntervalHook;
```

Comment: Use the overload of setCount which takes in the old value as a parameter, then increment that.

Comment: @Rotem do you mean using prevState and incrementing that?

Comment: Yes, `setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)`

Comment: I have tried to implement your code in codesandbox and it seems to be working fine for me.
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-browser-t8qi51?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to change some state based on its previous value, use a function:`setCount(count => count + 1);` and your `useEffect` becomes independant of `[ count ]`. Like

```
useEffect(() => {
  const tick = () => {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  };

  const interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };
}, [setCount]);
```

or you get rid of `tick()` and write.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(setCount, 1000, count => count + 1);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };
}, [setCount]);
```

But imo it's cleaner to use a reducer:

```
const [count, increment] = useReducer(count => count + 1, 0);

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(increment, 1000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };
}, [increment]);
```